# Is there a way to make a Text widget in Tkinter non-clickable and non-editable?

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible do make a Text widget in Tkinter non-clickable and non-editable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just set its state to "disabled":

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, DISABLED
r = Tk()
Text(r, state=DISABLED).grid()
r.mainloop()
```

You can even enter some text before you disable it.

```
from Tkinter import Tk, Text, DISABLED
r = Tk()
t = Text(r)
t.grid()
t.insert(0.0, "BLAH!")
# Just make sure you disable it AFTER you put the text in
t["state"] = DISABLED
r.mainloop()
```

Then I suppose you could set its background to be grey or something so that people know it is inactive.

**Edit**:

Since you asked, you can reactivate the textbox like this:

```
# Note you have to have NORMAL imported
t["state"] = NORMAL
```

Comment: Can i enable it again if i need? How?

Comment: @Jovito: If you look up `DISABLED` in the Tkinter docs, you will see the other states right next to it.

Comment: If the textbox is disabled, then there is no way to enter text into it. Therefore this is not useful.